# Sql INNER JOIN with Query order by Rand

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to re optimise this query it is very slow.

```
SELECT al.alias_title, al.title, al.hits, al.created_on, 
       u.first_name, u.surname, 
       uf.real_name, uf.user_name, 
       T.guid_id 
FROM album al 
INNER JOIN (SELECT imx.id, aix.album_id, imx.guid_id 
            FROM image imx 
            INNER JOIN album_image aix 
                       ON imx.id = aix.image_id 
            ORDER BY FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                                     FROM image))) AS T 
          ON al.id = T.album_id
LEFT JOIN user u 
          ON al.user_id = al.id
LEFT JOIN user_flickr uf 
          ON u.id = uf.user_id
WHERE al.approved ='Yes' 
      AND al.visible ='1' 
GROUP BY T.album_id 
ORDER BY al.title;
```

I need a random image to show each time for each gallery. There is a many to many relationship- image, album and album image. I need a random image for each album and then the albums to be order by title. I think inner queries and the rand function are very slow. I have looked at temporary tables but am unsure if this is the best way to go.

Comment: About how many images are there per-gallery?  Is this something that could be easily handled application-side?

Comment: You should start from using EXPLAIN before SELECT and see what it says. I see that you use ORDER BY RAND() in subquery. It is very bad approach. First off all, you need optimize this subquery. Perhaps, you do not need use aubquery and probably should do decomposition.

Comment: number of images per gallery varies quite considerable one may have one image another gallery may have 200 images

Comment: what is a better approach rather than order by rand()

Answer (score 1):

Sort randomly is not a good practice. It is better to use the LIMIT clause, generating a random value from the app (or even could be a sql variable) and then ask for a single record. Example

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ?, 1;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ?, ?+1;
```

PD: "?" could be a variable or input parameter

Comment: If you omit the random order by the query is faster? because it could be a problem handling the number of images or the size of them.

Comment: Maybe you agree paging query, a user can hardly see more than 10 images at a time ..

Comment: the idea is one image is select from each album and showed at random. A user then clicks to see images in an album

Comment: Yes, this used to view photos one at a time, but you can increase the limit and show more pictures.

What you should not do is show all pictures at once, you paginate, similar to how the albums in facebook, there if you have an album with 200 images do not display them all at you at 10 or sample maximum of 20, while going down the scroll, facebook is showing more pictures.

Thus the performance improvement and images not unnecessarily overloads, because no human can watch 200 images at once.